# Sump pump running constantly - water coming in FROM discharge pipe

Tags: plumbing, basement, sump-pump

I recently had the misfortune of a flooded basement due to a failed sump pump. While putting in the new pump, I noticed that there was a substantial amount of water coming into the sump pit FROM the sump discharge pipe, i.e. the place where water should be going OUT. In fact, were it not for the check valve in place it would've been near impossible to put in the new pump due to the amount of water coming in. I'm guessing this isn't normal by any means and why the old pump kept running every few minutes and eventually died (although it did last for 7 years.) What could be causing this constant backflow?

Comment: Where on the planet are you?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Ohio.

Comment: They have a thing there called the Great Black Swamp.  It has swallowed houses, railroads, even parts of Michigan.   This led a guy named James Hill to invent the Buckeye Ditcher, an easy way to set drain tile.  Tiles do get clogged or collapse; maybe that happened on your property or downstream.

Answer (score 1):

...An inappropriate discharge arrangement would seem to be the obvious answer. Changing the discharge pipe's path and/or destination would be the solution.